# angularjs:timeout not working in $http POST request

Tags: angularjs

I have the following snippet in my code which set a timeout in milliseconds for the request.But its not cancelled even if the timeout is met.

```
var httpURL = {
            method : URLobj.method,
            url : urlString,
            data : data,
            withCredentials : true,
            headers : URLobj.headers,
            timeout:200
    };

    this.$http(httpURL).success(successFunc).error(errorFunc);
```

Can someone please shed some light on how this timeout parameter can be used.I am using v1.2.26.

[image: service invocation]

Comment: Does your "successFunc" handler get executed?

Comment: yes SuccessFunc gets executed at a later time than the timeout tiime

Comment: If you look in the network section of your web browser developer tools, can you see the http call taking longer than 200msec?

Comment: Which version of angular do you use? I cannot find configs "successHandle" and "errorHandle" in 1.4.0 version

Comment: angular 1.2.26 is the version used.

Comment: in the httpURL config json please remove the successHandle : successFunc and errorHandle : errorFunc. There are no such configs in $http

Comment: @manasisakhare but they are working fine

Comment: But you've just made your config object invalid. Try putting the timeout before the success and error handles and see it if works?

Comment: they are working because you have added them in .success and .error callbacks respectively

Comment: @manasisakhare thank you!I tried after removing them but timeout is not applied

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest that doesn't work too

Comment: @manasisakhare I had `config.timeout = deferred.promise;` in one of my interceptor which had overridden the value that i have set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had config.timeout = deferred.promise; in one of my interceptor which had overridden the value that i have set. Commenting it out worked for me.

```
config.timeout = deferred.promise;
```

Comment: Hi @Divya MV, can you post full code? How do we get config and deferred objects here?

Answer (score 3):

This would be how you create a $http call with a timeout

```
$http({
        method: URLobj.method,
        url: urlstring,
        withCredentials : true,
        headers: URLobj.headers,
        timeout: 200
     }).success(function(data){
        // With the data succesfully returned, call our callback
        successFunc(data);
    }).error(function(){
        errorFunc("error");
    });
 }
});
```

Comment: I had `config.timeout = deferred.promise;` in one of my interceptor which had overridden the value that i have set.

Comment: Why is this marked as correct answer? I see no change with the original code but formatting.

Answer (score -1):

Below syntax will works

```
$http.post(url, parms, {timeout: 60000}).then(function(success){}, function(error){})
```