# Chrome:POST/OPTIONS requests Fails with net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, proxy, dns, xmlhttprequest

The OPTION/POST Request is failing inconsistently with a console Error as err_timed_out. We get the issue inconsistently, it's only observed sometimes. Otherwise the request gets proper response from the back end. When it's timing out, the request doesn't even reach the server.

I have done some research on the stuff and found that due to maximum 6 connections to a resource restrictions it may wait for getting a connection released. But, I don't see any other requests pending ,all the other requests were completed.

In the timeline I can always see that it stalled for 20.00 seconds. Most of the time the time is same. But, it only shows that its been stalled for some time nothing else in the timeline.

The status of the request shows failed ERR_Connection_Timed_Out. Please help.

#### The Network Timing

[image]

#### Console Error

[image]

Comment: How about the back-end part of the request? Do you have any control on that? Do you get a response calling the same request from a different machine?

Comment: @Yoann issue is inconsistent ,we get proper response otherwise.Updated the question .

Comment: Do you have error handler on your promise? I mean if you don't any other than ok will timeout when there is no handler catching them.

Comment: @mico we have a failure handler registered just like mentioned here.http://stackoverflow.com/a/29917375/4260544

Comment: What is your timeout value? The value in the answer is 200ms which may be too short for a test backend

Comment: Can you do an options request via Some Rest tool like [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) or [restconsole](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en)

Comment: @ElliotSwart We don't use any timeout.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this issue when I use an authenticated proxy server and usually a refresh of the page fixes it.

Are you using an authenticated proxy server where you are seeing this behavior? Have you tried on a pc with direct access (i.e. without proxy) to the Internet?

Comment: The issue is highly inconsistent.Can we somehow debug whats happening  to confirm its due to the Proxy.We are struggling to find the root cause.

Comment: If you see this documentation (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#resource-network-timing), this is explained in the section "Resource network timing". 

Excerpt for Stalled state: 
Time the request spent waiting before it could be sent. This time is inclusive of any time spent in proxy negotiation. Additionally, this time will include when the browser is waiting for an already established connection to become available for re-use, obeying Chrome's maximum six TCP connection per origin rule.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem when I choose another ISP. I thought I would have only to put my new ID and password, but it wasn't the case.
I have an ADSL modem with a dry loop.

All others services were fine (DNS resolution, IP telephony, FTP, etc).
I did a lot of tests (disable firewall, try some others navigator, try under Linux, modem default factory, etc) none of those tests were successful.

To resolve the problem `ERR_TIMED_OUT`, I had to adjust the MTU and MRU values. I put `1458` rather than `1492`, which is the default value. 
It works for me. Maybe some ISPs use different values. Good luck.